# Javascript and html hide a <p> container after onclick on button and send message if <input> is empty

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning Javascript right now and I got a problem (might be a small problem for you guys). Here is my code:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="number" id="number1" placeholder="like 0,25" />
<input type="number" id="number2" placeholder="like 200" />
<input type="number" id="number3" placeholder="like 0,30"/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p style="padding: 10px;
        width: 2em;
          border:3px green solid;" id="demo"></p>
<script>

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("number1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("number2").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("number3").value;


    var ergebnis = Math.round(eval("(x*x*y)/(z*z)"));
    var res = ergebnis;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    } 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I want that "error" will be displayed when the button is clicked and there is an empty input field. And that the `<p>` will be first displayed, when the button is clicked. I know that I can hide the `<p>` but I don't know how to make it visible after the click again.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, why are you using `eval` ? It's bad practice, but also the math will be evaluated to begin with.

Comment: Can you reformulate the questions? I can't understand what is exactly your goal.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. what does that have to do with anything? It's placeholder text.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Both are works in an input field + it's placeholder.

Comment: I'm using eval because I don't know it better and it works. My goal is that the var res will get the text "Error" when the User don't fill every input field with an number. And my second problem is, that the <p> with the border should only be displayed when the button was clicked. In my code the <p> with the border is always displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="number" id="number1" placeholder="like 0,25" />
<input type="number" id="number2" placeholder="like 200" />
<input type="number" id="number3" placeholder="like 0,30"/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p style="padding: 10px;
        width: 2em;
          border:3px green solid;display: none;" id="demo"></p>
<script>

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("number1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("number2").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("number3").value;


    var ergebnis = Math.round(eval("(x*x*y)/(z*z)"));
    var res = ergebnis;
    var resultbox = document.getElementById("demo");
    if(x && y && z){
    
    resultbox.innerHTML = res;

    resultbox.style.display = "block";
    resultbox.style.border = "3px green solid";
    resultbox.style.color = "black";
    } else {
     resultbox.innerHTML = "error";
    resultbox.style.display = "block";
    resultbox.style.border ="none";
    }
    
    } 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mkleber check if this is what you want.

Comment: Thats nice too, but the error should not be displayed in the border, sorry if I described it not clearly enough.

Comment: Very nice, thank you very much, thats exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Made it! Have a nice day

Comment: Could there be an other message like "choose a number over 0" instead of the word Infinity within the green border? When you choose for example the numbers 0,25, 20, 0 and click on Try it, the word Infinity will be displayed in the green border.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to evaluate the entered values
- Add a block `p` to show an error.
- If one field doesn't have value show the error.
- If all fields contain data hide the error and show the result.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("number1").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("number2").value;
  var z = document.getElementById("number3").value;

  var ergebnis = Math.round(eval("(x*x*y)/(z*z)"));
  var res = ergebnis;

  if (x.trim() === '' || y.trim() === '' || z.trim() === '') {
    document.getElementById("error").className = "";
    return;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("error").className = "hide";
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
  document.getElementById("demo").style.display = '';
}
```

```css
#error {
  color: red;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number1" placeholder="like 0,25" />
<input type="number" id="number2" placeholder="like 200" />
<input type="number" id="number3" placeholder="like 0,30" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<p id="error" class="hide">
  Some information is missing!
</p>

<p style="padding: 10px;
        width: 2em;
          border:3px green solid; display: none" id="demo"></p>
```

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: Thats what I wanted, thank you! I tried it and it looks nice, but one thing is not that nice. If i type 3 number in and let it calculate, the number is displayed with the border, like I wanted it. But if I delete some of the number s, the old number will be displayed and the text "some information is missing!" will be shown. How can just the text will be displayed without the old number?

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to change the inner content wether are the values were found, also I would recommend you not use inline css/js, you can instead use event listeners.

Everytime the functions is called it will clear out the result.

```js
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
function myFunction() {
    demo.innerHTML = '';
    var x = document.getElementById("number1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("number2").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("number3").value;

  if(x && y && z){
    var ergebnis = Math.round(eval("(x*x*y)/(z*z)"));
    var res = ergebnis;
    demo.innerHTML = res;

    //You can also clear the inputs
    x.value = '';
    y.value = '';
    z.value = '';
  }else{
     demo.innerHTML = 'Oops one empty imput!'; 
     //Or delete the else if you don't want to show an error
  }
    
} 

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number1" placeholder="like 0,25" />
<input type="number" id="number2" placeholder="like 200" />
<input type="number" id="number3" placeholder="like 0,30"/>

<button>Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Your code throw an exception : `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`

Comment: Sorry! Thought the variables were abc, fixed